# Play sound on fast clicks android

Tags: android, performance, audio, button, playback

I want to play a sound everytime that a button is pressed.

The problem is that, If I press it fast, then sometimes the sound plays.. But sometimes it does not play.

If I press a button 20 times, (very fast) then the sound should ideally play 20 times. But what happens is that the sound does not get time to complete. It plays 8-9 times on average.

I have initialised my mediaPlayer object. And this seems to work.

```
mp1.start();
```

I tried the following code too, But this plays the sound only the first time. After that the sound is never played.

```
if(mp1.isPlaying())
    mp1.stop();
    mp1.start();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is, MediaPlayer class is comparatively a heavy weight object and might not be suitable to play small files in a smaller interval. So my suggestion for you is to use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

SoundPool is comparatively a less weight object and will help in your case.

Here is a sample based on it,

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidMedia/article.html#tutorial_soundpool

Comment: Great! This Worked perfectly :) I use too this tutorial http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=207

Comment: wow. this is great. Thanks for pointing out another good example. I didn't know this.